# Using the function with multiple outputs (non-summary fxn?) with summarize

Tags: r, function, dplyr

```
library(OptimalCutpoints)

library(dplyr)
```

Here is a test data:

```
set.seed(123)

df<-data.frame(label=rbinom(1000,size=1,prob=0.5),score=rnorm(1000),type=sample(c("A","B","C","D"),1000,replace=TRUE))
```

Grouped the 'type' using group_by and wanted to summarize using the optimal.cutpoints function from  library(OptimalCutpoints)

```
df%>%group_by(type)%>%summarize(Opt_cut=optimal.cutpoints(X = "score", status = "label", tag.healthy = 0, methods = "MaxSpSe",data=df[,1:2]))
```

I got this :
`Error: expecting a single value`

I could get a workaround like this, extracting each "type" and running optimal.cutpoints separately:

```
df_A<-df%>%filter(grepl("A",type))
opt.cut.df.A <- optimal.cutpoints(X = "score", status = "label", tag.healthy = 0, methods = "MaxSpSe", data = df_A)
```

From opt.cut.df.A I can extract the optimal cutoff like so:

```
opt.cut.df.A[1]$MaxSpSe$Global$optimal.cutoff$cutoff
```

But this is definitely not the best way esp.  with large # of "types"
Unless I missed something, looks like summarize will work only with a single output function.

## Question: How to use optimal.cutpoints or similar functions with summarize?

Comment: The function outputs a nested list while `summarize` is not expecting that. Do you just want the single cut point?

Comment: Hi Pierre, In this case yes...but my general question is how to summarize groups with  functions that have >1 value output in dplyr. I think the apply  split solution by Psidom below works great! Maybe dplyr is not the best approach in this case.

Comment: I used `data.table` it was pretty fast. I tried `dplyr` but couldn't find a way

Comment: `summarize` can output list columns, which can be unnested via *tidyr* `unnest`.  See [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/832) for an example of `summarize` and a list column.  However, your particular case/function doesn't seem to work well - I get an error about the length of dimnames not being equal to the array extent...

Comment: @thisisrg If any of the solutions below solve your issue, please consider marking it as accepted using the green checkmark

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Ah yes...newbie here..didn't know that option. Thanks. I have found the data.table solution most straightforward...mostly because of my less familiarity with purr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,opt(.SD), by=type]
   type          V1
1:    A -0.07686590
2:    D  0.10719041
3:    D  0.11553210
4:    D  0.13909786
5:    B  0.16122635
6:    B  0.18304797
7:    C -0.08671413
```

where `opt` is the function for the cuts:

```
opt <- function(df) optimal.cutpoints(X = "score", status = "label", tag.healthy = 0, methods = "MaxSpSe", data=df)[1]$MaxSpSe$Global$optimal.cutoff$cutoff
```

The reason `dplyr` was not working is because sometimes a group has one cutoff point, sometimes it has multiple cuts. `summarise` is waiting for one value only, the mixed length vectors were creating problems.

Comment: Thanks!..yes definitely...I think that the cutoffs may have have >1 values escaped my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  split(.$type) %>%
  map(~ optimal.cutpoints(X = "score", status = "label", 
                          tag.healthy = 0, methods = "MaxSpSe", data = .)) %>%
  map(c("MaxSpSe", "Global", "optimal.cutoff", "cutoff"))
```

Which gives:

```
#$A
#[1] -0.0768659
#
#$B
#[1] 0.1612264 0.1830480
#
#$C
#[1] -0.08671413
#
#$D
#[1] 0.1071904 0.1155321 0.1390979
```

---

If you want the results in a data.frame, you can add `map_df` to the chain:

```
df %>%
    split(.$type) %>%
    map(~optimal.cutpoints(X = "score", status = "label", 
                           tag.healthy = 0, methods = "MaxSpSe", data = .)) %>% 
    map(c("MaxSpSe", "Global", "optimal.cutoff", "cutoff")) %>% 
    map_df(~data.frame(cutoff = .), .id = "type")
```

Which gives:

```
#  type      cutoff
#1    A -0.07686590
#2    B  0.16122635
#3    B  0.18304797
#4    C -0.08671413
#5    D  0.10719041
#6    D  0.11553210
#7    D  0.13909786
```

Comment: I was also thinking purrr might be the too to use for this.  With the addition of `map_df(as.data.frame, .id = "type")` you can coerce to a data.frame, but I have yet to figure out how to name the column of cutoff values.

Comment: @aosmith I was trying to figure out the same and ended up giving up ;P if you happen to find it please feel free to update my post. At some point I used `data.table::melt()` and managed to have `value` and `L1`

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use the `split`, `apply` method, generating a list of models and then extract values from the list.

```
listOfModels <- lapply(split(df, df$type), function(subDf) 
                       optimal.cutpoints(X = "score", status = "label", 
                                         tag.healthy = 0, methods = "MaxSpSe",data=subDf))

lapply(listOfModels, function(model) model[1]$MaxSpSe$Global$optimal.cutoff$cutoff)

$A
[1] -0.0768659

$B
[1] 0.1612264 0.1830480

$C
[1] -0.08671413

$D
[1] 0.1071904 0.1155321 0.1390979
```